# Swift how to declare JSON Object in class property

Tags: json, xcode, swift, objectmapper

I am just trying to map below JSON response into an object class.. Here I declared object class something like

```
    var response: Dictionary<String,Dictionary<Dictionary, Any>>!
    var Urls: [String]!
```

Here is my Json response formate

```
     {
Urls : [ <URI String>, ... ],
response: {
     Locations : [
         { < Location Object> },
         { < Location Object> }, ...
     ]
 }
```

}

Here Url [String] always but when I try to access the response it is always nil. Am I doing any declaration mistake here. Any suggestion would be greatly helpful

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Used ObjectMapper lib and I could get Url [String]! in my response object but var response getting as null always